# Trying to post two models with a single view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the next view that has a view model with two objects.

```
    @model prueba.ViewModel.InfoSolicitanteViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateSolicitante";
}

<h1>CreateSolicitante1</h1>

<h4>Solicitante</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="InfoPersonal.Ocupacion" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="InfoPersonal.Ocupacion" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="InfoPersonal.Ocupacion" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Create">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Solicitante.NombreSolicitante" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Solicitante.NombreSolicitante" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Solicitante.NombreSolicitante" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Solicitante.Numero" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Solicitante.Numero" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Solicitante.Numero" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </div>
```

The controllers are the same auto-generated ones, with the only exception that i told the info create Get controller what view to use so that both controllers use the same view. framework version is .NET core 2.2

right now i'm trying to post the models with a submit button each, but it only sends to the controller i access from the respective index. also, if there is a way to send both models to both controllers with only one submit, i would love to know that too. **Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

> right now i'm trying to post the models with a submit button each, but
> it only sends to the controller i access from the respective index.

Add `asp-controller` to specify which controller you want to post the data to.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-controller="InfoPersonals" asp-action="Create">
        //...
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-controller="Solicitantes" asp-action="Create">
        //...
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

> if there is a way to send both models to both controllers with only
> one submit, i would love to know that too.

I think you could use jquery change function to judge which input fill the value and then append corresponding action to the form:

```
@model InfoSolicitanteViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateSolicitante";
}

<h1>CreateSolicitante1</h1>

<h4>Solicitante</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="InfoPersonal.Ocupacion" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="InfoPersonal.Ocupacion" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="InfoPersonal.Ocupacion" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Solicitante.NombreSolicitante" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Solicitante.NombreSolicitante" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Solicitante.NombreSolicitante" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Solicitante.Numero" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Solicitante.Numero" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Solicitante.Numero" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>   
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name^='Solicitante']").change(function () {
            $('form').removeAttr('action');
            $('form').attr('action', '/Solicitantes/Create');
        });
        $("input[name^='InfoPersonal']").change(function () {
            $('form').removeAttr('action');
            $('form').attr('action', '/InfoPersonals/Create');
        });
    })
</script>
}
```

My testing model:

```
public class InfoSolicitanteViewModel
{
    public InfoPersonal InfoPersonal { get; set; }
    public Solicitante Solicitante { get; set; }
}
public class InfoPersonal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Ocupacion { get; set; }
}
public class Solicitante
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NombreSolicitante { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

Write something in the input field, and then press enter or click outside the field.It would trigger the change event.

[image]

Comment: i still have the same problem. Even after i specify with controller i want, it uses the controller i access from(i have the create view in the shared folder now, i thought that would change anything). let's say my fields and buttons are in the home view. i would love it if i can just use any of the two without the change of routes (or both at the same time, if possible).

Comment: How did you access the create view?Could you share more code?Actually,if you specify the asp-controller for the two forms,it could generate the correct url,be sure the controller name is correct.I suggest you could share the updated code you have.And share your simple controller would be better.

Comment: And you said you'd love to use any of the two without change of the route.If you do not change the route,how the buttons know which controller it should hit?Did you try my second way?The second way in my post is to change the url by jquery,does it still not work or not?

Answer (score 0):

> right now i'm trying to post the models with a submit button each, but it only sends to the controller i access from the respective index. also, if there is a way to send both models to both controllers with only one submit, i would love to know that too.

You can post both forms with one button using [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). First you need to give each form a unique id. Then leave only 1 submit button and also give it a unique id.

Then register a click event to listen for that button click. If that button is inside the form, it is important to prevent the default behavior of the form as well so that it doesn't submit the form when you click the button.

Here is an example of how to send requests via ajax with jQuery. I've give the forms ids of `solicitantesForm` and `infoPersonalsForm`. The button has an id of `submitButton` for this example:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submitButton').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var solicitantesFormData = new FormData(document.getElementById('solicitantesForm'));
                $.ajax({
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/Solicitantes/Create',
                    data: solicitantesFormData,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert('solicitantesForm submitted');
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert('error submitting solicitantesForm');
                    }
                });
                var infoPersonalsFormData = new FormData(document.getElementById('infoPersonalsForm'));
                $.ajax({
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/InfoPersonals/Create',
                    data: infoPersonalsFormData,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert('infoPersonalsForm submitted');
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert('error submitting infoPersonalsForm');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```